# Printing by matching argument with a string

Tags: optional-arguments, arguments

I want to 1) print `Robert` when the argument is not present, and 2) print `Alice` when the argument matches some string or print `Robert` when the argument does not match it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\myCommand} { O{} }
  {
     Alice (When #1 is Girl)
     Robert (otherwise)
   }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myCommand[Girl]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are using ExplSyntax and it looks like you are trying to match/compare strings, try looking into `l3str`.

Comment: it doesn't really help to completely change the example after answers have been posted. (I am sure you have been told that before) Your error is now completely different: you are using a `V` argument with `Girl` when that should be an `n` argument

Comment: there really is no need to duplicate the Robert branch just use `O{}` instead of `o` and the empty string will naturally take the non matching branch.

Comment: Will use `O{}` then as you say.  I changed it to show I want ta match strings.  Now there are the solutions for both a string and a pattern.

Comment: @Ragonese That is not the point. The point is how the site works. The content is not just for you and changing your question makes it more difficult for people to find the solutions they're looking for. We now have one question and, in effect, one answer to that question and one answer to a completely different question which can be inferred only indirectly. The search function is poor enough without deliberate sabotage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Alice if the argument contains d any number of p and c, otherwise Robert

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\myCommand} {O{}}
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF
      {dp*c} {#1}
      { Alice }
      { Robert }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

1 \myCommand

2 \myCommand[wibble]

3 \myCommand[xxxdpc]

4 \myCommand[dppppppppppc]

\end{document}
```

---

Or with the completely different question after your edit, using a string equality test for `Girl`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\myCommand} {O{}}
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF
      {#1} {Girl}
      { Alice }
      { Robert }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

1 \myCommand

2 \myCommand[wibble]

3 \myCommand[Girl]

4 \myCommand[xxxGirlxxx]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I interpreted "match" to mean a regex match obviously if you mean a string equality you could test for that with `str` module comparisons more efficiently (although the regexp cost doesn't really matter unless you have thousands of these)

Comment: I added a `str_if_eq` version.

Comment: From my experience even a few `regex`-replacements give a very noticeable slowdown (compare loading early versions of `ducksay` with current versions loadtime; there were maybe a few dozen `regex` calls at load time, still loading the package took around two seconds, iirc, nowadays that code is handled by `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` and is much faster).

Comment: @Skillmon I want perl regex:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want sed.

Comment: @cfr I must admit I use sed a lot more than perl:-)